# You rely on me to find your way. I'll always look in one direction

Tags: riddle

> You rely on me to find your way. I'll always look in one direction. Left, down, right and up. What am I?

The answer is useful for helping people when they are lost.

Comment: I think you've deleted the latest question where I told you: please **PLEASE** put the riddle in the ***body of your question***. This has been told to you multiple times. People have fixed this for you over and over. The puzzle should be *in the body*, not just the title.

Comment: I thought the body was meant for like hints

Comment: The body should have all the information needed to solve the puzzle. The title is a quick summary or "hook" for the puzzle (occasionally some oblique hints are in the title). The body is the full puzzle. I do believe I've told you this before.

Comment: This seems like more of a direct description of an object than an actual riddle.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is straightforward description, not puzzle-y

Comment: @Deusovi Any chance you could close this as *"This question may invite speculative answers"* *(it's true actually)*? Currently there are votes to close this as being too straightforward, but one could see this as users closing a question as "too simple"... not a very valid reason (in my opinion at least). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems obvious to me, so maybe I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure the answer is

> a compass.

Answer (score 0):

I think its

> Direction signs on streets